# How do I set an Ember.js select view's value when using objects for options?

Tags: ember.js

I'm having some trouble figuring out how to get Ember's select view to update the dom when using objects instead of strings. This example behaves how I would expect:

http://jsfiddle.net/XZ9b7/

Using only an array of strings for values, setting the bound property's value to a new value  by clicking the buttons will automatically update the dom and set the dropdown to the same value.

When using objects in this example however:

http://jsfiddle.net/pRBKt/

I tried setting the bound property's value to the id, value, and a copy of the option object itself, and I can't get it to affect the select view.

I just need a way to set the value of a select view when using objects for options

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've added an other button in your fiddle:

```html
<div><button onclick="App.someObject.set('letterSelection', App.someOptions.objectAt(0));">real a</button></div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Sly7/BYjk6/#base

I think you have to use the same object, but not a copy. So in your case you have to pick up the object from the array bound to the Ember.Select's content property.

EDIT: jsfiddle using #each and {{action}}. I think it cleans up the template and the code.

http://jsfiddle.net/Sly7/sCr8T/

```html
<script type="text/x-handlebars">
  {{view Ember.Select
    contentBinding="App.someOptions"
    selectionBinding="App.someObject.letterSelection"
    optionLabelPath="content.val"
    optionValuePath="content.id"
  }}
  {{App.someObject.letterSelection.val}}
  {{#each option in App.someOptions}}
    <div>
      <button {{action "updateSelection" target="App.someObject" context="option"}}>{{option.val}}</button>
    </div>        
  {{/each}}
</script>
```

JavaScript:

```js
window.App = Ember.Application.create();

App.someObject= Ember.Object.create({
  title: "Some Title",
  letterSelection: null, 

  updateSelection: function(event){
    var newSelection = event.context;
    this.set('letterSelection', newSelection);
  }
});

App.someOptions = [
  {'id':'id_a','val':'a'},
  {'id':'id_b','val':'b'},
  {'id':'id_c','val':'c'},
  {'id':'id_d','val':'d'}
];
```

Comment: You're welcome :). BTW, by reading your fiddle, I saw that your ember version seems very old. I you can track changes, I'd suggest you to use master, or at least the latest stable release 0.9.8.1

Comment: oh that must have been because I googled ember jsfiddle and used a template, I'm using a later version for actual dev

Comment: fine, so I update my answer, using #each and {{action}} helper. I think this is a neater implementation.

Comment: Can I use both selectionBinding and valueBinding in Ember.Select

Comment: @Matt. Re-reading the doc http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Select.html (which pretty detailed IMO), it seems it's possible, even if I don't understand why you want both.